# Calculating the output current and voltage of series and parallel connected solar panels

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, solar-system

I have two solar panels, one is rated as $I=2A$ (current) and $V=20V$ (voltage) and the other as $I=3A$ and $V=15V$. If I connect them in parallel, how to calculate the current and voltage of the parallel connected system?

What about if I arrange them as a series circuit?

Thank you for any help!

P.S. Please let me know if you need more information or clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all steady state circuit analysis things in parallel share the same voltage, and things in series share the same current. The question then really boils down to what the current vs. voltage curve looks like for a solar panel.

A quick search turned up this:
[image: Solar Panel I-V curve]
from https://www.folsomlabs.com/modeling/module/module_model

So in this case it looks like you could approximate this type of curve as constant current until the voltage requirement is met and then constant voltage.

In that case, in series they would conduct the lower of the two current limits, each at their voltage limits so $I=2A$ $V=35V$

In parallel they would would be at the lower of the two voltage limits and their currents would sum: $I=5A$ $V=15V$

Note that the power output of either of these combined circuits is less than the sum of the potential power output of the individual panels. This can actually have a dramatic effect in real solar panel arrays as the current limit is proportional to the amount of light received so if there are many panels connected in series, only one of which is shaded the output would be the same as if all of the panels were shaded.

Comment: Putting the panels in series is bad for the reason you said: The 2A panel will limit the current to 2A, and the 3A panel will be forced to operate far from its optimum power point. But putting the panels in parallel _could_ be worse. In that case, the 15V panel will drag the voltage of the "20V" panel down to 15V by _dissipating some of the power_ that is generated by the 20V panel. Whether or not this could overheat and damage the 15V penel is an open question. (IDK how to find the answer except by doing the experiment.)

Answer (score -1):

Photovoltaic power generation uses series connection because the current generated by photovoltaic cells is weak. Although a single damaged panel can render the entire solar panel ineffective, this can be controlled by increasing the strength of the solar panels.

Solar panels of the same specifications can be connected in either series or parallel, depending on the desired voltage. Series connection involves connecting them end to end, and the current remains constant while the voltage is multiplied by the number of panels (N). Parallel connection involves connecting them head to head and tail to tail, and the current is multiplied by N while the voltage remains constant.

This depends on the output voltage of each panel. Regardless of series or parallel connection, solar panels usually cannot be directly used for household appliances because they produce direct current (DC). A control circuit or battery charging is required, followed by an inverter to convert the DC to 220V alternating current (AC) for household use.

Two solar panels can be connected in series to double the output voltage. If you want to increase the current while keeping the voltage constant, parallel connection is necessary. However, since the two panels may not receive the same amount of sunlight, the generated voltage may vary. Therefore, when connecting them in parallel, a diode must be added to prevent reverse current flow.